# Locate tool.exe through search function and then execute it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making batch-files for fun and i ran in to a problem. I've search for a solution and i havn't found anyone.

I'de like to code my batch file so it will search for a specific file on my c: drive and after it found the pathlocation I want it to execute. Can it be done?

I don't know if i can combine the path I get from "dir tool.exe /s /p" somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using batch

```
for /f %%i in ('dir C:\tool.exe /s /b') do (
    start %%~fi
    exit /b
)
```

Consider the fact that if your executable is located deep down the folder tree it will take some time to actually find it and run. So if you want to improve the performance you might narrow down a search a bit if it is an option of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir tool.exe /s /p') do set "var=%%A"
start %var%
```

The output of 'dir tool.exe /s /p' is saved in var which you can then use to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for batch, but here is as a powershell option because I was bored:

```
Get-ChildItem / -Recurse -File | % { if($_.Name -eq "notepad.exe") { &$_.FullName; break} }
```

It will execute the first hit on the search for "notepad.exe" and then exit the script.